# Houndify: Web SDK Sample: signed token rejected

Tags: houndify

I've been away from coding for a few years so excuse the simple nature of this question.  I've downloaded the Houndify web sdk and followed instructions to get it running on my local web server (localhost).  When running it I get the authentication error "signed token rejected".  I've updated the config.json and index.html with my client ID and Key.  Any ideas?

E W

Answer (score 0):

Can you check:

- if you have activated your account by clicking the link in the email
- test the request from the API console from the Client dashboard page

I have had the same error and realized that my account was not activated.